# php strip_tags() troubles

Tags: php

I am making a project posting system that will have somewhat some markup, similar to bbcodes, When i'm fetching the data from the database I use

```
strip_tags($content,'<br />');
```

To remove any unwanted html tags, then I continue on to use

```
str_ireplace($markup,$html_t,$strip_tags);
```

And those are both placed in variables for easier working.
I want to allow the `<br />` tag because that is what is in my database to achieve line downs (nl2br) now for some reason it's not echoing out `<br />`'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No whitespace in second param.

```
strip_tags($content,'<br>');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Oh, thanks!  I would have never thought of that because in the database it's <br />, thanks ALOT though!